# Personal View/Database for users

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, view, asp.net-mvc-5

I´m working on a movie database with asp.net mvc5 and as a user you should be able to select movies, for a personal list of movies you have already watched. My problem is I´m new and I have no clue whats the best way to start realizing such a thing.
The main thing which I´m struggling is the thought that I have to have a own database for each user, correct? If yes how can I start here?

Thanks a lot for tips in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of database as an Excel file. You only need one Excel file (database). Rename "sheet1" to "movies" (create table in database) and write all movies on this sheet. Create another sheet and name it "users" and write all users on this sheet. Create a third sheet, name it "watched" and write in the first column user row number from the second sheet and movie row number from the first sheet.

There you have it - a single database with three tables:

> movies (id, name)
>
> 1 Matrix
>
> 2 Avatar
>
> 3 Serenity

-

> users (id, name)
>
> 1 Max
>
> 2 Kevin

-

> watched(id, userid, moovieid)
>
> 1 1 2 //it means I watched Avatar
>
> 2 1 3 //it means I watched Serenity
>
> 3 2 1 //it means you watched Matrix

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Beschreibung. Das heißt ich kann das einfach als Many-to-Many anlegen. Ich habe irgendwie zu kompliziert gedacht.

Comment: Yes, it's actually not that hard. Once you grasp the idea you never falter again. Only one remark if I may. Relations will be not Many-to-Many but 1-to-Many since "movies" table has only unique values and "watched" table can have many instances of the same movie. Same applies to "users" table.
P.S. I don't speak German but google translates it surprisingly well.